# Flask Redirect with parameter

Tags: python-2.7, redirect, flask

Ideally I would like to return this, but it doesn't work:

```
return redirect(url_for('register'), message='email already exists')
```

I've tried this version without the url_for:

```
return redirect('register.html', message='email already exists')
```

does not work either. Do you have to return the message explicitly in the url or save it in a cookie? Is there not a cleaner way to do it?

Thank you for help

Comment: Honestly, sounds like it'd be neater for you to `flash('email already exists')` then `return redirect(url_for('register'))` and then look for and display flashed messages in the view template.

Comment: Exactly - [`flask.flash`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#message-flashing) sounds like *exactly* what you are looking for (under the hood it uses a cookie, but it takes care of all of the handling for you).  What is the reason `flash` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for), the parameters should be pass in the url_for, **not the redirect.**

```
return redirect(url_for('register', message='email already exists'))
```